# SQL Query - Need to get distinct values

Tags: mysql

I have a data like below. I need to get the distinct Col 1 values where it has both "aaa" and "bbb" as Col 2 values.

Sorry, just starting to learn SQL on my own.

my table

```
|--------|----------|
| Col 1  | Col 2    | 
|--------------------
| 1      | aaa      |
| 1      | bbb      |
| 2      | aaa      |
| 2      | ccc      |
| 3      | aaa      |
| 3      | bbb      |
| 3      | ccc      |
|--------|----------|
```

Result should be below.

```
|--------|
| Col 1  | 
|--------|
| 1      | 
| 3      | 
|--------|
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your query.

Comment: I have tried to do a subquery, however, it would result to nothing.SELECT DISTINCT Col1 FROM table
WHERE Col  = '1' AND
Col1 IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT Col1 FROM table
WHERE Col  = '2')